# Error in compiling x264 on ARM 64-bit platform

Tags: c, arm, x264

The same x264 source code I compiled on [Debian 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_10_(Buster)) (Buster) system has no problem, but I can't compile it on an ARM 64-bit platform. Why?

Maybe there is something wrong with the Makefile, but I don't know where it is.

1. Configure

   ```
   ./configure --disable-asm --enable-shared  --host=aarch64-linux

   platform:      AARCH64
   byte order:    little-endian
   system:        LINUX
   cli:           yes
   libx264:       internal
   shared:        yes
   static:        no
   asm:           no
   interlaced:    yes
   avs:           avxsynth
   lavf:          no
   ffms:          no
   mp4:           no
   gpl:           yes
   thread:        posix
   opencl:        yes
   filters:       crop select_every
   lto:           no
   debug:         no
   gprof:         no
   strip:         no
   PIC:           yes
   bit depth:     all
   chroma format: all
   ```
2. Edit file *config.mak*,

   ```
   SRCPATH=.
   prefix=/usr/local
   exec_prefix=${prefix}
   bindir=${exec_prefix}/bin
   libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
   includedir=${prefix}/include
   SYS_ARCH=AARCH64
   SYS=LINUX
   CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
   CFLAGS=-Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wshadow -O3 -ffast-math  -Wall -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -std=gnu99 -
   D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-tree-vectorize
   COMPILER=GNU
   COMPILER_STYLE=GNU
   DEPMM=-MM -g0
   DEPMT=-MT
   LD=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o
   LDFLAGS= -lm -lpthread -ldl
   LIBX264=libx264.a
   AR=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar rc
   RANLIB=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
   STRIP=aarch64-linux-gnu-strip
   INSTALL=install
   AS=
   ASFLAGS= -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=16 -DPIC
   RC=
   RCFLAGS=
   EXE=
   HAVE_GETOPT_LONG=1
   DEVNULL=/dev/null
   PROF_GEN_CC=-fprofile-generate
   PROF_GEN_LD=-fprofile-generate
   PROF_USE_CC=-fprofile-use
   PROF_USE_LD=-fprofile-use
   HAVE_OPENCL=yes
   CC_O=-o $@
   default: cli
   install: install-cli
   SOSUFFIX=so
   SONAME=libx264.so.157
   SOFLAGS=-shared -Wl,-soname,$(SONAME)  -Wl,-Bsymbolic
   default: lib-shared
   install: install-lib-shared
   LDFLAGSCLI = -ldl
   CLI_LIBX264 = $(LIBX264)
   ```
3. Make, an error occurred, details in [error](https://pastebin.com/WhvCY1fd).
4. Add file *config.h* after configure,

   ```
    #define HAVE_MALLOC_H 1
    #define ARCH_X86_64 1
    #define SYS_LINUX 1
    #define STACK_ALIGNMENT 64
    #define HAVE_POSIXTHREAD 1
    #define HAVE_CPU_COUNT 1
    #define HAVE_THREAD 1
    #define HAVE_LOG2F 1
    #define HAVE_STRTOK_R 1
    #define HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME 1
    #define HAVE_MMAP 1
    #define HAVE_THP 1
    #define HAVE_AVS 1
    #define USE_AVXSYNTH 1
    #define HAVE_VECTOREXT 1
    #define fseek fseeko
    #define ftell ftello
    #define HAVE_BITDEPTH8 1
    #define HAVE_BITDEPTH10 1
    #define HAVE_GPL 1
    #define HAVE_INTERLACED 1
    #define HAVE_OPENCL (BIT_DEPTH==8)
    #define HAVE_ALTIVEC 0
    #define HAVE_ALTIVEC_H 0
    #define HAVE_MMX 0
    #define HAVE_ARMV6 0
    #define HAVE_ARMV6T2 0
    #define HAVE_NEON 0
    #define HAVE_BEOSTHREAD 0
    #define HAVE_WIN32THREAD 0
    #define HAVE_SWSCALE 0
    #define HAVE_LAVF 0
    #define HAVE_FFMS 0
    #define HAVE_GPAC 0
    #define HAVE_LSMASH 0
    #define HAVE_X86_INLINE_ASM 0
    #define HAVE_AS_FUNC 0
    #define HAVE_INTEL_DISPATCHER 0
    #define HAVE_MSA 0
    #define HAVE_WINRT 0
    #define HAVE_VSX 0
    #define HAVE_ARM_INLINE_ASM 0
   ```

Comment: Almost all error are "undefined reference" erros, did you forget to include some libs?

Comment: @Ackdari  I guess so, but I don't know what's missing? Because I didn't find the relevant information.

Comment: It seems to compile but fails to link. All undefined references start with `x264_`. I would expect them to be in `libx264.a`. Can you dump its contents using `nm libx264.a`?

Comment: @Codo There is indeed a libx264.a file in the current folder. I don't know how to use the nm command? Just nm libx264.a? It outputs a lot of information.

Comment: solved it by run ./configure --disable-asm --enable-shared --enable-static and modify
ASFLAGS= -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -f elf64 -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=64 in the same time,but I don't know why?

Comment: What was the output of config.h after configure? I am mostly interested in values of HAVE_ARMV6/HAVE_AARCH64/HAVE_NEON defines.

Comment: Also libx264.so.157 suggest that you are trying to compile version before this fix: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/x264/-/commit/7114174b23b1764b8f4b58ae9d0f8a422748df0f

Comment: @nobody555 I have added config.h in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by running

```
./configure --disable-asm --enable-shared --enable-static
```

and modifying at the same time

```
ASFLAGS= -I. -I$(SRCPATH) -f elf64 -DSTACK_ALIGNMENT=64
```

Comment: Are you sure that you still compile it for aarch64? Because your config.h suggest that you are compiling for x86_64 (#define ARCH_X86_64 1).

Comment: @nobody555 yes,I have cross-compiled ffmpeg with x264 successfully.But I wonder why I can't compile successfully according to the flow in my question?

Comment: Because you use old version of x264 code that had bug when compiled for aarch64 with asm disabled. It was fixed in commit I linked above but you use older version.